# Bootstrap 4 Validate Form Remove Red Glow

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have 2 form fields in form-group

```
<form action="" method="post" was-validated>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email address:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

If nothing is entered and form submitted, red glow on both inputs.

What CSS class can I use to change this?

I have tried:

```
.form-control: is-invalid {
    background: red;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I put background: red just so I can test and see results clearly. It is the CSS class that is the important factor.

Comment: Possibly a HTML5 class?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one:

```
.form-control {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood the original question. I have updated to remove the "red-glow" from the inputs.

EDIT 2: Removed the outline as well

Try this:

```
.was-validated .form-control:invalid,
.was-validated .form-control:invalid:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried but still no joy. I was thinking something along the same lines as your edited code, but still shows that damn red glow

Comment: Updated answer to remove outline as well. if this doesn't work, there might be other classes overriding it. In this case, you may want to add !important.

Comment: Tried this also, and with !important. I think it might be HTML5 input class maybe? Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```css
.form-control:invalid {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. This changes all the form outlines though, I only want the red glow removing. Thanks though, appreciate the response

Comment: Oh, try changing outline to none like I edited with `:invalid`.

Comment: Ahh, now this kinda works. However, its changed it even if the form wasn't submitted. So I guess I need to extend this a little?? Maybe with 'was-validated'

Comment: 'form-control was-validated:invalid' no joy

Comment: So usually grey border, turns red when submitted (without input) but with this its turned the border red constantly, even without submit

Comment: I think this might be a HTML thing you know, buddy!

Comment: which browser are you using?..Did you add the css properly? Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Using Firefox and BS4

Comment: Okay, you can try using `novalidate` on form element or remove required if you don't want validation and in your code you used was-validated that should be added as a class to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having similar issues, my issue was with HTML5 and FireFox. I used this to resolve the issue

```
:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output) {

}
```